# Improving accuracy of Homography + SIFT method

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, sift

I'm using Homography + SIFT to find out the position of each object's pixels in image source in image distination, i've got a very good matching using sift but when i tested the homography results some points of image source placed in wrong position in image distination for exemple: [image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEvqf.png) [image distination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taNDo.png) [matching image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsGRM.png)

this is my code:

```
image1_points = []
img = cv.imread('../dataset/masks-crop/7.png', cv.CV_16U)          # queryImage

plt.imshow(img)
for i in range(img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(img.shape[1]):
        if(img[i, j] > 0):
            image1_points.append(j)
            image1_points.append(i)
            
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
img1 = cv.imread('../dataset/views-crop/view_7/016.png', cv.CV_16U)          # sourceImage
img2 = cv.imread('../dataset/views-crop/view_8/024.png', cv.CV_16U)          # distImage
# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv.SIFT_create()
img1 = cv.normalize(img1, None, 0, 255, cv.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv.CV_8U)
img2 = cv.normalize(img2, None, 0, 255, cv.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv.CV_8U)
# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks = 50)
flann = cv.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
# store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75*n.distance:
        good.append(m)
        
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
if len(good)>=MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    M, mask = cv.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv.RANSAC, 50.0)

    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()
    h,w = img1.shape
    print(len(image1_points))
    pts = np.float32(image1_points).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst = cv.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)
    
    
else:
    print( "Not enough matches are found - {}/{}".format(len(good), MIN_MATCH_COUNT) )
    matchesMask = None
    
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    
draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0), # draw matches in green color
                   singlePointColor = None,
                   matchesMask = matchesMask, # draw only inliers
                   flags = 2)
img3 = cv.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,**draw_params)
plt.imshow(img3, 'gray'),plt.show()
cv.imwrite('./matching.png', img3)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


i1 = cv.imread('../dataset/views-crop/view_7/016.png', cv.CV_16U)          # sourceImage
i2 = cv.imread('../dataset/views-crop/view_8/024.png', cv.CV_16U)          # distImage

i1 = cv.circle(i1, (int(pts[4000][0][0]),int(pts[4000][0][1])), 1, [255,0,0], 8)
i2 = cv.circle(i2, (int(round(dst[4000][0][0])),int(round(dst[4000][0][1]))), 1, [255,0,0], 8)

i1 = cv.circle(i1, (int(pts[10000][0][0]),int(pts[10000][0][1])), 1, [255,0,0], 8)
i2 = cv.circle(i2, (int(round(dst[10000][0][0])),int(round(dst[10000][0][1]))), 1, [255,0,0], 8)

i1 = cv.circle(i1, (int(pts[30000][0][0]),int(pts[30000][0][1])), 1, [255,0,0], 8)
i2 = cv.circle(i2, (int(round(dst[30000][0][0])),int(round(dst[30000][0][1]))), 1, [255,0,0], 8)

i1 = cv.circle(i1, (int(pts[20000][0][0]),int(pts[20000][0][1])), 1, [255,0,0], 8)
i2 = cv.circle(i2, (int(round(dst[20000][0][0])),int(round(dst[20000][0][1]))), 1, [255,0,0], 8)

i1 = cv.circle(i1, (int(pts[500][0][0]),int(pts[500][0][1])), 1, [255,0,0], 8)
i2 = cv.circle(i2, (int(round(dst[500][0][0])),int(round(dst[500][0][1]))), 1, [255,0,0], 8)

i1 = cv.circle(i1, (int(pts[22000][0][0]),int(pts[22000][0][1])), 1, [255,0,0], 8)
i2 = cv.circle(i2, (int(round(dst[22000][0][0])),int(round(dst[22000][0][1]))), 1, [255,0,0], 8)

i1 = cv.circle(i1, (int(pts[21600][0][0]),int(pts[21600][0][1])), 1, [255,0,0], 8)
i2 = cv.circle(i2, (int(round(dst[21600][0][0])),int(round(dst[21600][0][1]))), 1, [255,0,0], 8)

i1 = cv.circle(i1, (int(pts[21550][0][0]),int(pts[21550][0][1])), 1, [255,0,0], 8)
i2 = cv.circle(i2, (int(round(dst[21550][0][0])),int(round(dst[21550][0][1]))), 1, [255,0,0], 8)

i1 = cv.circle(i1, (int(pts[21690][0][0]),int(pts[21690][0][1])), 1, [255,0,0], 8)
i2 = cv.circle(i2, (int(round(dst[21690][0][0])),int(round(dst[21690][0][1]))), 1, [255,0,0], 8)


i1 = cv.circle(i1, (int(pts[21690][0][0]),int(pts[21690][0][1])), 1, [255,0,0], 8)
i2 = cv.circle(i2, (int(round(dst[21690][0][0])),int(round(dst[21690][0][1]))), 1, [255,0,0], 8)

i1 = cv.circle(i1, (int(pts[23690][0][0]),int(pts[23690][0][1])), 1, [255,0,0], 8)
i2 = cv.circle(i2, (int(round(dst[23690][0][0])),int(round(dst[23690][0][1]))), 1, [255,0,0], 8)

i1 = cv.circle(i1, (int(pts[23990][0][0]),int(pts[23990][0][1])), 1, [255,0,0], 8)
i2 = cv.circle(i2, (int(round(dst[23990][0][0])),int(round(dst[23990][0][1]))), 1, [255,0,0], 8)


i1 = cv.circle(i1, (int(pts[25690][0][0]),int(pts[25690][0][1])), 1, [255,0,0], 8)
i2 = cv.circle(i2, (int(round(dst[25690][0][0])),int(round(dst[25690][0][1]))), 1, [255,0,0], 8)

i1 = cv.circle(i1, (int(pts[12000][0][0]),int(pts[12000][0][1])), 1, [255,0,0], 8)
i2 = cv.circle(i2, (int(round(dst[12000][0][0])),int(round(dst[12000][0][1]))), 1, [255,0,0], 8)

i1 = cv.circle(i1, (int(pts[12800][0][0]),int(pts[12800][0][1])), 1, [255,0,0], 8)
i2 = cv.circle(i2, (int(round(dst[12800][0][0])),int(round(dst[12800][0][1]))), 1, [255,0,0], 8)

i1 = cv.circle(i1, (int(pts[12900][0][0]),int(pts[12900][0][1])), 1, [255,0,0], 8)
i2 = cv.circle(i2, (int(round(dst[12900][0][0])),int(round(dst[12900][0][1]))), 1, [255,0,0], 8)

i1 = cv.circle(i1, (int(pts[28200][0][0]),int(pts[28200][0][1])), 1, [255,0,0], 8)
i2 = cv.circle(i2, (int(round(dst[28200][0][0])),int(round(dst[28200][0][1]))), 1, [255,0,0], 8)

plt.imshow(i1)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(i2)
plt.show()

cv.imwrite('./testing/i1.png',i1)
cv.imwrite('./testing/i2.png',i2)
```

**Edit**

after i increased matches number: [image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDTVy.png) [image distination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSdIl.png) [matching image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjmcg.png)

Comment: Perhaps you are not getting enough good matches. How many good matches do you get?

Comment: 10 matches, you can see the matching result in matching image link

Comment: Homographies are only correct for a planar scene (or purely rotated camera around the projection center), so for a 3D object geometry you will always observe errors from a single homography!

Comment: 10 matches are likely not going to give a very good result in a least squares sense if they do not fit the distortion model for perspective homography. What residuals do you get of the actual points to the perspective model fit?

Comment: @Micka thanks for your comment, what do you suggest as alternative method to solve my problem (find the position of each object's pixels in image of the next view) or at least to reduce errors

Comment: Do you know the 3D geometry of the object? The right "transformation" is the fundamental matrix, but it can only describe the correspondence up to projectivity, afair.

Comment: @fmw42 thanks for your comment, for this view even if i increase the number of matches i will not have a good resutls, sorry i didn't understand your question

Comment: @Micka i want to estimate the fundamental matrix from images

Comment: Why do you need the homography? Afair 8-point algorithm is used there.

Comment: @Micka my main goal is to extract all object's pixels and know there positions in all views, so i decided to use homography to know the position of each pixels from view in other views

Comment: have a look at this: https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi03/cse291-j/lec7.pdf